# Parsing a site using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

For my school project, I'm trying to scrape some data from this site (http://www.boxofficemojo.com/monthly/?view=releasedate&chart=&month=1&yr=2006). I went through the documentation of beautifulsoup, but I'm having an issue now.
Here is the setup so far.

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_source = urllib.urlopen('http://www.boxofficemojo.com/monthly/?
view=releasedate&chart=&month=1&yr=2006').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
```

I was first trying to get the titles first, but then when I looked into the html code, I noticed that the tags contain neither id nor class. So at first, I tried `soup.find_all(href=re.compile("movies"))`, because the tag looks something like `<td><b><font size="2"><a href="/movies/?id=bigmommashouse2.htm">Big Momma's House 2</a></font></b></td>`, and href always starts with "/movies" for title sections. But then as I pointed out, this gave me not only titles, but also gave me unnecessary value from the top of the page, because the tag looks pretty much the same `<a href="/movies/?id=beautyandthebeast2017.htm">#1 Movie: 'Beauty and the Beast'</a>`

Then I tried `soup.select("td b font a")`, and this also gave me garbage values because they also have the same nested structure. Are there any ways I can only get the titles? Eventually, I have to get the data of title, total gross, open and close column from the table as csv file for each month and each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **lxml** module (an order of magnitude faster than BeautifulSoup if coded properly) to fetch the data from the url provided something like this :

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.boxofficemojo.com/monthly/?view=releasedate&chart=&month=1&yr=2006"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = html.fromstring(response.content)
result_list = []
for row in soup.xpath('//div[@id="body"]/center/table')[0].xpath('.//tr')[2:] : 
    # print row.xpath()
    data = row.xpath('./td//text()')
    print data
    if len(data) >= 8 :
        print data
        result_list.append({'title' : data[1].strip(), 'gross' : data[3].strip(),
            'open' : data[7].strip(), 'close' : data[8].strip()})

print result_list
```

This will result in :

```
[{'close': '6/1', 'gross': '$70,165,972', 'open': '1/27', 'title': "Big Momma's House 2"}, {'close': '3/12', 'gross': '$62,318,875', 'open': '1/20', 'title': 'Underworld: Evolution'}, {'close': '2/16', 'gross': '$47,326,473', 'open': '1/6', 'title': 'Hostel'}, {'close': '5/4', 'gross': '$47,144,110', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Nanny McPhee'}, {'close': '5/11', 'gross': '$42,647,449', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'Glory Road'}, {'close': '3/9', 'gross': '$38,399,961', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'Last Holiday'}, {'close': '4/13', 'gross': '$17,127,992', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Annapolis'}, {'close': '3/30', 'gross': '$14,734,633', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'Tristan and Isolde'}, {'close': '3/9', 'gross': '$11,967,000', 'open': '1/20', 'title': 'End of the Spear'}, {'close': '6/25', 'gross': '$10,407,978', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Roving Mars (IMAX)'}, {'close': '2/23', 'gross': '$6,090,172', 'open': '1/6', 'title': "Grandma's Boy"}, {'close': '1/22', 'gross': '$2,405,420', 'open': '1/6', 'title': 'BloodRayne'}, {'close': '4/6', 'gross': '$2,197,694', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Rang De Basanti'}, {'close': '5/18', 'gross': '$1,439,972', 'open': '1/20', 'title': 'Why We Fight'}, {'close': '5/4', 'gross': '$1,253,413', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Tristram Shandy: A Cock and Bull Story'}, {'close': '3/9', 'gross': '$888,975', 'open': '1/20', 'title': 'Looking for Comedy in the Muslim World'}, {'close': '3/23', 'gross': '$672,243', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Imagine Me and You'}, {'close': '1/29', 'gross': '$332,491', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'Zinda'}, {'close': '3/9', 'gross': '$274,245', 'open': '1/20', 'title': 'Dirty'}, {'close': '5/4', 'gross': '$196,857', 'open': '1/6', 'title': 'Fateless'}, {'close': '2/23', 'gross': '$145,626', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Bubble'}, {'close': '3/23', 'gross': '$78,378', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Manderlay'}, {'close': '2/12', 'gross': '$65,429', 'open': '1/20', 'title': 'The Real Dirt on Farmer John'}, {'close': '2/26', 'gross': '$55,398', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'That Man: Peter Berlin'}, {'close': '8/24', 'gross': '$53,580', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'La Petite Jerusalem'}, {'close': '2/2', 'gross': '$29,710', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'Henri Cartier-Bresson: The Impassioned Eye'}, {'close': '4/6', 'gross': '$24,038', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'When the Sea Rises'}, {'close': '1/16', 'gross': '$20,055', 'open': '1/11', 'title': 'State of Fear'}, {'close': '4/9', 'gross': '$17,341', 'open': '1/13', 'title': 'Film Geek'}, {'close': '3/30', 'gross': '$16,377', 'open': '1/13', 'title': "April's Shower"}, {'close': '1/29', 'gross': '$11,290', 'open': '1/27', 'title': 'Live Freaky! Die Freaky!'}, {'close': '1/26', 'gross': '$5,716', 'open': '1/20', 'title': 'Pizza'}]
```

You can refer to the documentation of [scraping](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) for more understanding.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!! I'll go ahead and look at documentation of xpath stuff.

Comment: By the way, is there a way that the resulting list won't be sorted by alphabetical order? I want it as it was appended..

Comment: It is in the same order as the source page as you can see from the code that no sorting logic is used.

Comment: Never mind. I found out that I can access each element by something like this way `result_list[0]['title']`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find current table. 
You can see that content located inside "center" tag.
Ok, try: `soup.find('center')`. Current table is first, so: `table = soup.find('center').find_all('table')[0]`.
 
Now in this table try to find links: 
`trs = table.find_all('tr')
trs = iter(trs)
next(trs) #skip first element
for tr in trs:
    try:
        print tr.find_all('a')[0]['href']
        print tr.find_all('a')[0].get_text()
    except:
        print "can't find a"`

Comment: I actually thought about skipping the first one, but then I couldn't get the other attributes nicely altogether. But thank you though!!

Answer (score 0):

Here another ( a not 'beautiful' one ;) ) approach working also in case of (erronous) variations of the tags or the page structure:

```
htmlSection = html_source[html_source.find('<a href="/movies/?id=')+21:]
# ^--- skip the first occurence (it doesn't belong to the table of interest)
while htmlSection.find('<a href="/movies/?id=') > 0  :
    htmlSection = htmlSection[ htmlSection.find('<a href="/movies/?id=') : ]
    htmlSection = htmlSection[htmlSection.find('>') : ]
    titleEndPos = htmlSection.find('</a>')
    strTitle = htmlSection[1:titleEndPos]
    print(strTitle)
```

Based on the .find('headerText'/'trailerText') principle you can extract also any other information using only basic Python string operations.

Comment: As I replied in the other answer, I also thought about skipping the first one, but couldn't format as I wanted. But thanks though! I'll look up how htmlSection works.

Comment: This kind of a 'not beautiful' approach shows it's advantages in case the html page is malformed and it is hard to find the cause of the problem looking at the strange results or error messages from the other approaches. As long as the source code of the html page is 'beautiful' you won't see the reason why is it worth to consider not to deal with any xml/html modules.